# Can not render value with Vuejs, but console log work fine

Tags: javascript, rest, get, vue.js

I getting started with VueJS and must say it works amazing, though trying the Vue-Resource implementation, does only work half the time.

When pulling data from my server, it seems like it wont finalize the data.

An example is the following code, where in I have loaded a request from my server, but it will only load half the data.

The response I am trying to insert into the parser, looks like this.

[{ city: "New York", amount: 8 }, { city: "San Francisco", amount: 18 }]

The issue is when I am logging it to the console it works fine, but rendering removes the amount. Never the city, only the amount from each location.

Can anybody tell me how this happens. I can only find solutions from Vue.js 0.9, but I am using Vue.js 2.3.3 and Vue-resource 1.3.3.

```
vm = new Vue({
el: '#devApp',
data: {
    citiesCount: [],
},
mounted: function()
{
    this.getLocationsCityCount();
    this.getLatestLocations();
},
methods: {
    getLocationsCityCount: function(cb)
    {
        var test = this.$http.get('/api/v1/locations/count/cities').then(
            success => {
                console.log(success.body.response);
                this.citiesCount = success.body.response;
            },
            error => {
                console.log('error');
                console.log(error);
            }
        );
    },
}
```

});

Comment: Show the template

Answer (score 0):

It is not the template, but here you go, I have tried with static data.

Here is the template:

```
<div id="devApp" class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title">Location amount per city</h4>
</div>

<ul class="list-group location-list">
    <li class="list-group-item" v-for="item in citiesCount">@{{item.city}}<span class="badge">@{{item.amount}}</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

the @ `@{{ data }}` sign is only needed in laravel blade.

and yes you just need to loop through your data to display everyone of it

here's a working sample.

https://jsfiddle.net/khenxi/djcner34/

Comment: I am using Laravel. I think the issue is with my browser, since it works fine in other browsers and after I reinstalled my browser (Google Chrome 59). It works again?!

Comment: What was the version of your old Chome? Better check the compatibility since you are using ES6.